# Windows Defender block calling application from another one

Tags: c++, windows, security, antivirus, windows-defender

I have an application consistsing of two binaries - a self-made game (Game.exe) and a launcher (Launcher.exe) for it. Launcher.exe is calling Game.exe with specific command line parameters and looking is game process haven't ended. Launcher app is written using C++ (MinGW) with Qt framework.

Everything's ok on my development PC (with Windows Defender disabled).
Everything's ok on my test PCs (with Windows Defender disabled too).

But on some PCs it encounters several problem on Windows 10/11. Game.exe is being executed from launcher with some features being restricted, so it just fails to work properly. If its being called from a console, there is no limitations.

Root of problem is Windows Defender which finds behaviour of my launcher app kinda suspicious. I've tested it and sure about that.

I can't really get away from a Game.exe and Launcher.exe separation (a historical moment about separating a codebase, just take it as it is). I can't just tell all my users to disable Windows Defender. And it's too expensive to buy a certificate from Microsoft for a small homebrew game.

So is there a way to overcome this?